# Consulta en MySQL

Tags: mysql

Buena tardes, tengo una base de datos su nombre es socialdb.

Tengo las siguientes tablas:

**usuarios** (id_usuario, nombre, correo, contraseña).

**amigos** (id_amigo, envio_user, recibio_user, estado)

**publicaciones** (id_pub, usuario_id, comentario, avatar, fecha_creacion)

---

¿Qué necesito?

El usuario con id 4 envió la solicitud al usuario con la id 7, entonces la tabla amigos queda así:

amigos(1, 4, 7, 1), cómo pueden observar id_amigo es un A_I, el campo envio_user aparece el usuario que envió la solicitud en este caso el usuario 4, el campo recibio_user aparece el id del usuario que recibió la solicitud en este caso el usuario 7 y por último el estado en 1, que significa que son amigos por que la solicitud fue aceptada.

¿Bien y ahora?.

Resulta que el usuario con id 4 ha enviado y recibido solicitudes, de una u otra forma su id se repitirá en envio_user o recibio_user, para lo que entonces sólo necesito sus id de amigos supongamos (7 - 25 - 21 - 90). Luego de esto entonces necesito sacar de publicaciones toda la información de publicaciones partiendo del usuario_id los amigos que resultaron de la consulta anterior.

**Propósito:** Es limitar las publicaciones que sólo puedan ver las de sus amigos y no la de todo el público en general.

Comment: Creo que no se alcanza a comprender bien tu pregunta, ademas de entrada tus campos de y para estan mal nombrados ya que no expresan un atributo de la tabla Amigos.

Comment: Si, acabo de hacer un ejemplo revisa por favor.

Comment: ¿podrías simplificar la pregunta?

Comment: que numero es el que se repite?

Comment: Mira es sencillo, la tabla amigos almacena en (de y para) el id del usuario ya sea que esté enviando o recibiendo una solicitud. Digamos el usuario No. 1 envió cinco solicitudes por lo que al hacer mi select anterior saldría 5 rows pero repitiendo el usuario No.1 lo que no me interesa, necesito son los otros usuarios para así saber quienes son sus amigos.

Comment: Luego de que digamos sus amigos son los usuarios No. (4 - 5 - 7 - 8 - 50), ahora con ellos necesito sacar las publicaciones un SELECT * FROM publicaciones where usuario = 'los usuarios que encontró como amigos'.

Comment: No es sencillo.. las columnas que salen son las que pedis en el select. El 1 va a estar incluido, ya que de alguna forma pertenece a un lado u otro de la relacion. no es que podes no mostrarlo. No trates de solucionar un problema de la vista con querys a la base de datos. La base de datos solo devuelve las filas que le pedis, lo otro lo tiene que resolver tu vista. Entonces tu problema es que ves el uno en las filas?

Comment: Hagamos una cosa, ya corrijo la pregunta en su totalidad, espera un momento.

Comment: Bien listo, por favor revisan y me comentan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Algo así podría funcionar:

```
SELECT * FROM publicaciones where usuario_id = 1
UNION
SELECT * FROM publicaciones where usuario_id in(
    SELECT envio_user from amigos where recibio_user = '1' AND estado ='1'
    UNION
    SELECT recibio_user from amigos where envio_user = '1' AND estado ='1'
)
```

Ahora alguien mas metido con sql seguramente pueda mejorar esta query para hacerla mas performante.

Comment: Déjame lo reviso, por favor.

Comment: Está perfecto, muestra las publicaciones de sus amigos una cosa así cómo viendo el resultado, cómo muestro también las de ese usuario en este caso No. 1, para que muestre las suyas y las de sus amigos.

Comment: Perfecto, gracias.